# How to compile multiple all testbench components of Systemc

Tags: bash, compiling, gcc, c++, g++

I have been trying to simulate all my testbench components of hierarchiral full adder systemc program. Previously,  to simulate a simple systemc filenamed(hello_world.cpp) I have used:

```
$ g++ -g -Wall -I $SYSTEMC_HOME/include hello_world.cpp -c
$ g++ -o hello_world.run hello_world.o -L $SYSTEMC_HOME/lib -lsystemc
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$SYSTEMC_HOME/lib
$ ./hello_world.run
```

Now that I have following :

```
half_adder.h
full_adder.h
full_adder.cpp
driver.h
driver.cpp
monitor.h
monitor.cpp
full_adder_main.cpp
```

My problem is how should i simulate all this files? I do not know bash scripting and also to write a makefile. I have recently started using ubuntu. I will be learning soon. Till then, could you please guide me.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This should get you started: [Managing Projects with GNU Make, 3rd Edition: Chapter 1. How to Write a Simple Makefile](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/managing-projects-with/0596006101/ch01.html)

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I have a doubt, does makefile uses Bash Scripting? As for this eg: count_words: count_words.o lexer.o -lfl
        gcc count_words.o lexer.o -lfl -o count_words

Comment: No, the `make` program uses its own syntax - some elements are similar to the bash shell (such as the use of `$` to expand variables) but they are not the same.

Comment: ooh okay. Thank you

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver your guidance has lead me to the solution!

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solution!

```
g++ -g -Wall -I $SYSTEMC_HOME/include half_adder.cpp full_adder.cpp driver.cpp monitor.cpp full_adder_main.cpp -c

g++ half_adder.o full_adder.o driver.o monitor.o full_adder_main.o -L $SYSTEMC_HOME/lib -lsystemc

./a.out
```

These are the commands I executed on my terminal.Before that make sure you have your environment variable set.
The environment variable setting(as shown in the question) are later added to bash.rc file

I am still learning how to write a makefile, but these commands will definitely help!

Thank you